# PHP post_max_size and upload_max_filesize don't change after edit

Tags: php

After installing Prestashop, I edit my php.ini to change the value of post_max_size and upload_max_filesize (128MB each). But nothing change after I restarted apache (still at 8MB and 2MB in the phpinfo() page).

Here's the info:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

PHP version

```
PHP 7.2.24 (cli) (built: Oct 22 2019 08:28:36) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Apache version

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (centos)
Server built:   Nov  4 2020 03:20:37
```

Centos version

```
CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011
```

Comment: cli and apache and fpm all have different php.ini files.  You need to look in /etc/php/7.4/ (on debian, dunno for centos) , and edit the appropriate file (s)  : fpm/php.ini and/or apache2/php.ini

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `phpinfo();` when called from the webserver (not CLI) to your question.

Comment: I use the command in the answer below and it works. But I don't remember installing this service, maybe installed automatically with php (sorry, quit new with php). And why some other option are take in account with restarting this service (like the extensions) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do this :

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain more details, such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this service was installed (quit new to php ;) )